# How to test components with ng-content

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component which depends on transclusion. I want to test it by calling it with different versions of inner HTML. How can I do it?

```
<div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Now I would like to write a test which puts an HTML into the component. It could look like this:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent, '<app-mycomponent>My testing content</app-mycomponent>');
```

Comment: So many hits for "transclusion angular"...

Comment: Yes, but nothing on how to test it.

Comment: You've read the Angular docs on testing transclusion directives?

Comment: I've read https://angular.io/guide/testing and haven't found anything on this subject. Do you know a better source?

Comment: I found https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing but at this point I don't know what the sticking point is.

Comment: These are for angularjs, but I couldn't find anything for angular